# Preamp effect on Android?

Tags: audio, music, equalizer

I know there are many equalizers on Android. But are there any preamp filters to make sound distorted a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Music Folder Player ([free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.zorillasoft.musicfolderplayer&hl=en) / [full](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.zorillasoft.musicfolderplayer.donate&hl=en)) has a built-in pre-amp option.
Also you can use PlayerPro Music Player ([free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbig.playerprotrial&hl=en) / [paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbig.playerpro&hl=en)) and [PlayerPro DSP pack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbig.playerpro.soundpack&hl=en)